# check if a file contains substring and ends with certain extension

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use the python regular expression to check if a string contains some given substring and also ends with a certain expension

for example, given `some_processed_file.mp4.gz`, I want to check if `processed` is in the string and it ends with `mp4.gz`

But even doing something like:

```
x = 'some_processed_file.mp4.gz'
re.search(r'/processed/', x)
```

Even this returns None. I must confess I do not really understand regular expressions but I thought this should look for substring anywhere in the input string.

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? How about splitting by a `.`?

Comment: I might want to make this a bit more flexible later on that is why I decided to go with regex but somehow cannot get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.search('processed.*\.mp4\.gz', x)
```